# Rails 5 will not submit my form to create route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I press "submit" on my form, it does not route to the :create route. When I press "submit" it keeps going to the :new route with my params in the url. I just upgraded to Rails 5 and using bootstrap. Have no clue on what I'm doing wrong.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pizzas#index'
  resources :pizzas
  resources :toppings
end
```

Rails routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pizzas#index
      pizzas GET    /pizzas(.:format)            pizzas#index
             POST   /pizzas(.:format)            pizzas#create
   new_pizza GET    /pizzas/new(.:format)        pizzas#new
  edit_pizza GET    /pizzas/:id/edit(.:format)   pizzas#edit
       pizza GET    /pizzas/:id(.:format)        pizzas#show
             PATCH  /pizzas/:id(.:format)        pizzas#update
             PUT    /pizzas/:id(.:format)        pizzas#update
             DELETE /pizzas/:id(.:format)        pizzas#destroy
```

PizzasController

```
class PizzasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @pizzas = Pizza.all
  end

  def new
    @pizza = Pizza.new
  end

  def create
    @pizza = Pizza.new(pizza_params)
    render text: params.inspect
  end

  private

  def pizza_params
    params.require(:pizza).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb View

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Create Your Own Pizza:</h1>

  <form class="form-horizontal">
  <%= form_for(@pizza) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>

      <%= f.submit %>

  <% end %>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: the `<%= form_for(@pizza) do |f| %>` automatically creates the <form> tag, so you had 2, which is incorrect HTML. The outer form didn't have an action so it was doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out after spending hours on it.

So for some reason the  tag does not comply. Not sure if its a Rails issue or Bootstrap. You have to change them to  tags like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Create Your Own Pizza:</h1>

  <div class="form-horizontal">  // Changed this to a Div Tag
  <%= form_for(@pizza) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>

      <%= f.submit %>

  <% end %>  
  </div>  // Changed this to a Div Tag
</div>
```